# Parse error body in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular

I would like to ask if how can I parse the error body that the API return to me.

This is the image of the API return:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
login(username,password){
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');

        return this.http.post(this.configEnvironment.url() + "oauth/access_token",
            JSON.stringify(
                {
                    username: username,
                    password: password,
                    grant_type: "password",
                    client_id: "xxxxxxx",
                    client_secret: "xxxxxxxx"
                }
            ),
            { headers }
        )
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch((err:any) =>{
            console.log(err);
            return Observable.throw(new Error(err));
         });

     }
```

I can access  the URL,status,statusText and etc using this:

```
err.status,err,url,error.statusText
```

My problem is i can't get the value of the error body.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `catch` is actually receiving a `Response`. You can access its details with `json()`

```
import { Response }  from "@angular/http";
...
.catch((err:Response) =>{
            let details = err.json().error;
            console.log(details);
            return Observable.throw(new Error(details));
         });
```

note: This answer is about the `@angular/http` library. As of Angular 5, this library is deprecated in favor of `@angular/common/http`

Comment: @SydneyLoteria No problem. You'll get better IDE assistance if you change the type of `err` from `any` to `Response` as I've just done.

Comment: What's the Angular 5 @angular/common/http method?